# R: Is there a rolling mean function with trimmed values for each window?

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm trying to do a moving average (similar to roll_mean in `RcppRoll`) except that, at *each* window, I'd like to trim the outliers (e.g. just take the 5th-95th percentile of values).

As an example, given a rolling window of

```
v <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

And given that I'd like the 10th-90th percentile of values, I should get an answer of `5.5` (1 and 10 will be excluded, and a mean is taken on the rest of the values (2 to 9).

I'm unfortunately not able to use functions like `RcppRoll::roll_mean` for this, since the trimming needs to be done at each rolling window.

I was able to do this by feeding a custom mean function to `zoo::rollapply` - but it's simply working too slowly for my use case (>1e6 rows).

I've looked at various packages that support rolling functions (e.g. `RcppRoll`, `zoo`, `TTR`, `caTools`, `roll` etc.) but none of them seem to support this trimming functionality.

I'm thinking of resorting to using Rcpp to build a custom, fast roll function, but am relatively unfamiliar with that framework. Not sure if there are better solutions.

Any help will be appreciated here.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you Please give a [mcve]? Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example ... then edit your question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43666402/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function in base-R that is a lot faster than `zoo::rollapply`.  It is probably possible to streamline it further, but the principle seems to work.  It avoids the sort on each window by using a 'rolling' sorted vector `vec` and just updating it for the old and new elements as the window rolls.

```
require(zoo) #just for comparison at the end
require(microbenchmark)
data <- sample(1:100,1000,TRUE)

rollMeanTrim <- function(dat,window,trim){
   n <- length(dat)-window+1
   out <- rep(NA,n)
   exc <- round(trim*window)
   vec <- sort(dat[1:window])
   out[1] <- mean(vec[(1+exc):(window-exc)])
   for(i in 2:n){
      old <- dat[i-1]
      new <- dat[i+window-1]
      oldpos <- match(old,vec)
      vec <- vec[-oldpos]
      newpos <- match(1,sign(vec-new))
      if(is.na(newpos)) {
         vec <- c(vec,new)
      } else if(newpos==1) {
         vec <- c(new,vec)
      } else {
         vec <- c(vec[1:(newpos-1)],new,vec[newpos:(window-1)])
      }
      out[i] <- mean(vec[(1+exc):(window-exc)])
   }
   return(out)
}

microbenchmark(rollMeanTrim(data,10,0.1),rollapply(data, 10, mean, trim=0.1))

Unit: milliseconds
                                  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
           rollMeanTrim(data, 10, 0.1)  63.4825  81.2573 149.4777  98.8031 146.4868 1163.929   100
 rollapply(data, 10, mean, trim = 0.1) 213.8742 330.3273 659.2942 412.7529 773.4881 2761.591   100
```

Comment: thanks! Great to see that even base-R can provide a leg up over zoo for this case. I ended up needing a 2-3 order magnitude speedup, though, so ended up going the Rcpp route

Comment: Yes, I was surprised, but I suppose a specific routine is often going to beat a generalised one.  How much faster did the Rcpp solution turn out to be?

Comment: i got a ~100x speedup via Rcpp on about 1e6 rows

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do something like

```
rollapply(data, 10, function(x) mean(x[x>=quantile(x,0.1) & x<=quantile(x,0.9)]))
```

Comment: I tried doing that but the zoo functions like rollapply are terribly slow for larger data sets - so will likely need something implemented using Rcpp

Comment: Have you tried the `trim` option in `mean` - e.g. `rollapply(data,10,mean,trim=0.1)`?  Might be a little faster.

Comment: This answer suggests that it might be faster in base-R than using zoo::rollapply... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090336/why-is-zoorollmean-slow-compared-to-a-simple-rcpp-implementation